# What was the purpose of the two buckets in the movie Papillon (2017)

Tags: papillon-2017

In the movie Papillon (2017), the main character is sent to another prison called *silent* prison. Were one of the buckets meant for use as a toilet?

Comment: *"Papi opens his eyes, hears the sound of sliding metal -- his water bucket has just been pushed inside.  The little metal door slides shut.  The sound of the Sweeper walking away... "* - The first one is for water and food going in. The other is for water and food going out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one of the buckets were meant to be used instead of a toilet. See the wikipedia article for [Slopping out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slopping_out)